# How do I have the footer of a page shows first in the HTML

Tags: css, seo, footer, sticky-footer

I need my footer to display last on the page but show first in the HTML. Can this be done and can someone point me to references?

Comment: Doesn't sound very semantic. May I ask why? Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: I agree with Andre, if it really holds footer data it shouldn't be first in the html. But if otherwise you have something in the beginning of the html that you want to display at the bottom of the content, you could also use jQuery to reposition the element.

Answer (score 1):

With a fixed postion you can put the mark-up anywhere on the page and position it with `bottom:0`, like so:

```
footer {
    postion: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```